# Output is trash value

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

This is my code. Is any wrong? This project is about **sorting in descending**, I did check some samples code on internet, but it's pretty same as me. But My code always print trash value memory.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void input(int a[], int n)
 {
    for( int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
 }
 void sort(int a[], int n)
 { 
    int i; int j; int temp;
    for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)

        for( j=i+1;i<n;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]<a[j])
                {
                temp =a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
                }

            }

 }
 int output(int a[], int n)
{
    for ( int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<' ';
    }

}

 int main()
 { 
 int n;
 cin>>n;
 int a[n];
 input(a,n);
 sort(a,n);     
 output(a,n); 
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `cin>>n; int a[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime value.  Use `std::vector<int> a(n);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's a compiler extension probably.

Comment: What trash values does it output? Can you give an example?

Comment: Your bug is here: `for( j=i+1;i<n;j++)` notice you use `i` instead of `j` for the loop condition this is a typo.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, it works.

Comment: @user253751 it returned like 32215477

Comment: And what was the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change `i<n` to `j<n` on your inner for loop in sort function.It might helps :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void input(int a[], int n)
 {
    for( int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
 }
 void sort(int a[], int n)
 { 
    int i; int j; int temp;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)

        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]<a[j])
                {
                temp =a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
                }

            }

 }
 int output(int a[], int n)
{
    for ( int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<' ';
    }

}

 int main()
 { 
 int n;
 cin>>n;
 int a[n];
 input(a,n);

 sort(a,n);     
 output(a,n); 
 return 0;
 }
```

Now If you want second max value, you can get from `a[n-2]`.